# Can two players play games on one computer with two monitors, keyboards and mice?

Tags: gaming

Can two persons play on one computer with separate monitors, keyboards and mice?

Comment: Can't think of a reason to even try and accomplish that...if you've already got 2 of everything then just buy a second pc right?

Comment: @M.Bennett I fail to see how duplicating hardware when one could do the job is ideal. Furthermore, I'll take a $1000 PC over two $500 ones - especially if the second one is only for light occasional use.

Comment: i don't need two pcs because most of the time it's just me using. Friends come over but not often. At that time we want to play together or do separate stuff.

Answer (score 3):

That's called a multiseat computer.  So long as the computer is powerful enough and the game compatible, you can use one for gaming too.

Here's a video of two people playing Starcraft II on one computer:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77hk2mYj-6U

Comment: Can you provide more info? How does it work, etc.?

Comment: In the video they are using SoftXpand Duo 2011 which I've never seen but it appears to work well  :)  You can also use Windows Multipoint Server or various flavours of Linux.  Newer versions of Fedora support multiseat out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I think makes it possible:

1. The game must support game play of 2 different players in 2 different monitors.
2. Use of Virtual machines, that is if your pc has enough processing power.